React Keyckloak Always 401 response when fetching Token after Client authentitifcation is switched to ON
I'm using React and trying to integrate Keycloak with it using ReactKeycloakWeb and Keycloak JS. I added the following configuration, which usually works fine:
const keycloakConfig = {
  realm: "webapp", // Realm as configured in Keycloak
  url: "http://localhost:8080",
  clientId: "webapp-client", // Client ID as configured in the realm in Keycloak
};

const keycloak = new Keycloak(keycloakConfig);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <ReactKeycloakProvider
        authClient={keycloak}
        initOptions={{
          onLoad: "login-required",
        }}
      >
        <ThemeProvider theme={mdTheme}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <Root />
          <Toaster />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </ReactKeycloakProvider>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};

export default App;

I created a user manually in Keycloak, and I was able to successfully connect to the application. However, I have many users, and I cannot create each user manually every time. So, I created users via the Keycloak API.
The problem is that to access the Keycloak API, I have to switch client authentication to ON, like this:

After enabling this, a new window appears in Keycloak for adding a secret key under "Credentials":

However, after adding this parameter, I am unable to connect to my app via React.

Even if I change the Keycloak web configuration like this:
const keycloakConfig = {
  realm: "webapp", // Realm as configured in Keycloak
  url: "http://localhost:8080",
  clientId: "webapp-client", // Client ID as configured in the realm in Keycloak
  credentials: {
    secret: 'hM6oswdupEMFkRzkBuhOfTPhC64s8G9R', // Only include this for confidential clients
  },
};

The same error appears, and the ReactKeycloakWeb package does not pass the client secret in the payload:

Is there a solution, or does the ReactKeycloakWeb package not work when client authentication is ON?

when you set client authentication usually is when you need another server to connect keycloak, now you are storing a client_secret on the client side which is not a good practice, you should have a client for your react app and another client to connect keycloak admin and add users etc

I guess this is because http (not https): May not be used in an insecure context.
